# How to remove items count from Compare products link in header

Tags: magento2, frontend, toplinks

I don't want to remove the whole link from frontend theme I just want to remove a part of the link.
I don't know where the file that I should edit it 
any help?

Answer (score 0):

The PHTML file for header compare product is 
***MAGENTO-ROOT/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/compare/link.phtml***

you can copy the PHTML file to your them and comment out the line as below

Original code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare Products') ?>"
       data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
    >
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare Products') ?>
        <span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"[data-role=compare-products-link]": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>}}
</script>
```

Change the phtml code it to

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<li class="item link compare" data-bind="scope: 'compareProducts'" data-role="compare-products-link">
    <a class="action compare no-display" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare Products') ?>"
       data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"
    >
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare Products') ?>
        <!--<span class="counter qty" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption"></span>-->
    </a>
</li>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{"[data-role=compare-products-link]": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>}}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks that helped :)